# Is there any package to read table from file in python

Tags: python, tabular

I've stored some data in a file in tabular format using the python package:  **tabulate**

```
>>> print tabulate(table, headers, tablefmt="orgtbl")$
```

The table looks like:

```
| name   |   num |
|--------+-------|
| abcd   |    30 |
| efgh   |   100 |
| ijklm  |    10 |
```

Now I need to feed this data to some other program(written in python).
Is there any easy way(I mean any package) to read the table into some data structure instead of parsing it explicitly. In other words  I could have printed the table into some other format(e.g: grid, pipe, media-wiki, latex) is there any ready made solution to read it into a data structure from any of such formats?

Comment: If you need to reuse it later then why would you store the data like that?

Comment: Don't! Store it in a way that's easy to parse, such as CSV, or JSON.

Comment: @shuttle87 Maybe OP wants it in a human friendly format. If you have a grudge against the `tabulate` module, maybe you could address that with the developers.

Comment: I certainly have no grudge against formats but if the goal is to share the data with other programs I can't help thinking that it would be easier to serialize the data in a different format if you have control over the source code.

Comment: markdown -> html -> xpath -> csv

Comment: I think that output in this format can be, with some effort, parsed using `csv`  module.

Comment: @shuttle87 OP clearly asked _" I could have printed the table into some other format(e.g: grid, pipe, media-wiki, latex) is there any ready made solution to read it into a data structure from any of such formats?"_ He is looking for some sort of uber table parser. Simply saying don't use grids, pipes, media-wiki or latex is bizarre.

Comment: [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) claims to be the swiss-army knife of document converters. It may help.

Comment: That's why I had the disclaimer about having control over the source code, if you don't then your suggestion of pandoc is definitely a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look at [astropy.io.ascii](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/ascii/#supported-formats) (previously known as [Asciitable](http://cxc.cfa.harvard.edu/contrib/asciitable/)) and see if it does some of what you want.

> The following shows a few of the ASCII formats that are available, while the section on Supported formats contains the full list.
>
> - Basic: basic table with customizable delimiters and header configurations
> - Cds: CDS format table (also Vizier and ApJ machine readable tables)
> - Daophot: table from the IRAF DAOphot package
> - Ecsv: Enhanced CSV format
> - FixedWidth: table with fixed-width columns (see also Fixed-width Gallery)
> - Ipac: IPAC format table
> - HTML: HTML format table contained in a <table> tag
> - Latex: LaTeX table with datavalue in the <kbd>tabular</kbd> environment
> - Rdb: tab-separated values with an extra line after the column definition line
> - SExtractor: SExtractor format table

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any easy way(I mean any package) to read the table into some data structure instead of parsing it explicitly.

With some effort, `csv.reader` will do:

```
from csv import reader

with open('table') as f:
    next(f) # throw away header
    next(f) # throw away |-----+-----|
    for line in reader((l.strip().strip('|') for l in f), delimiter='|'):
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
[' abcd   ', '    30 ']
[' efgh   ', '   100 ']
[' ijklm  ', '    10 ']
```

Not perfect, but close.

But, parsing it manually is in my opinion more readable:

```
with open('table') as f:
    next(f) # throw away header
    next(f) # throw away |-----+-----|
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip().strip('|').split('|'))
```

Throwing away redundant spaces also it's quite easy:

```
with open('table') as f:
    next(f) # throw away header
    next(f) # throw away |-----+-----|
    for line in f:
        print([scalar.strip() for scalar in line.strip().strip('|').split('|')])
```

Output:

```
['abcd', '30']
['efgh', '100']
['ijklm', '10']
```

That said, I would use `tabulate` only for displaying data. For storing, I'd use `csv` or `json`.